# Logstash not conditionally filtering based on Filebeat's fields

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I am trying to feed Zabbix log data into an ELK stack to do some timing correlations. However, I'm not getting the filter specified by my Logstash centralized server configuration that I would if it was acting as an agent. I'm using Filebeat to send the log entries to Logstash for processing. However, the `fields.tags` line is not being acknowledged by Logstash, but is visible in Elasticsearch/Kibana. Here are my configs.

```
filebeat: 
  prospectors: 
    - 
      paths:
        - /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.log
      input_type: log
      fields: 
        tags: ["zabbix", "zabbix-proxy"]
  registery_file: /var/lib/filebeat/registry
output: 
  logstash: 
    hosts: ["elkls.com:5044"]
logging: 
  files: 
    rotateeverybytes: 12345656
```

and then my Logstash configuration file

```
input { 
  beats { 
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter { 
  if "zabbix" in [fields.tags] {
    grok { 
      match => { 
        "message" => {
          "filter stuff here"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { 
    hosts => [ "elkhost.com:9200"]
  }
}
```

Logstash isn't acting upon the `fields.tags` line, and filtering/cutting up the log lines being passed to it from Filebeat. Am I accessing those variables correctly? I do something similar with other files, but only when Logstash is acting as an agent, and reading directly from a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if "zabbix" in [fields.tags] {
```

use

```
if "zabbix" in [fields][tags] {
```

To refer to a nested field in Logstash, you specify the full path to that field: `[top-level field][nested field]`.

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#logstash-config-field-references

Comment: I'm not at my work computer, but this makes sense now that I think about it. I don't think I would've found this looking myself. Thank you